The rank of a matrix expression
I'm studying discrete-time LTI systems and state estimators for them. Recently, I studied this paper. I am facing a matrix rank calculation problem and having trouble solving it. I will provide more details below and would appreciate any help.
Consider the discrete-time LTI system with the following state-space representation:
\begin{align}
    {x}_{k+1}&={A} {x}_k+{B} {u}_k  &;{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}, {B} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m} \\ 
    {y}_k&={C} {x}_k  &;{C} \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times n} 
\end{align}
where $ {x}_k \in \mathbb{R}^n $ is the state, $ {u}_k \in \mathbb{R}^m $ is the control input and $ {y}_k \in \mathbb{R}^p $ is the measured output.
Suppose, this system is controllable and observable, also assume that $\mathrm{N}=\mathrm{n}$. So the controllability matrix $B_N$ and the observability matrix $O_N$, which are constructed as follows, are of rank $n$.
$$
\begin{aligned}
& B_N=\left[\begin{array}{llll}
A^{N-1} B & \cdots & A B & B
\end{array}\right] \\
& O_N=\left[\begin{array}{c}
C \\
C A \\
\vdots \\
C A^{N-1}
\end{array}\right] \\
\end{aligned}
$$
I want to find the rank of matrix $M$, which is defined as below. The M matrix appears when we want to write the state of the system at any time based on the previous inputs and outputs of the system.
\begin{equation}
     x_k=M\begin{bmatrix}
                     u_N(k-N) \\
                     y_N(k-N) 
                   \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation*}
  u_N(k-N)={\begin{bmatrix}
             u_{k-N}^T & u_{k-N+1}^T & \cdots & u_{k-1}^T 
           \end{bmatrix}}^T
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
  y_N(k-N)={\begin{bmatrix}
             y_{k-N}^T & y_{k-N+1}^T & \cdots & y_{k-1}^T 
           \end{bmatrix}}^T
\end{equation*}
$$
\begin{aligned}
& T_N=\left[\begin{array}{ccccc}
0 & 0 & \cdots & \cdots & 0 \\
C B & 0 & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
C A B & C B & \ddots & \ddots & 0 \\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 0 \\
C A^{N-2} B & \cdots & \cdots & C B & 0
\end{array}\right] \\
& O_N^{+}=\left(O_N^T O_N\right)^{-1} O_N^T \\
& M=\left[B_N-A^N O_N^{+} T_N \quad A^N O_N^{+}\right] \\
&
\end{aligned}
$$
Through simulation with different examples, I observe that the rank of matrix $M$ is $n$, and I am seeking either a proof of this statement or a counterexample.

This question is also asked here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4946262/calculate-the-rank-of-a-matrix-expression
